# grepした結果のうち、特定の行のみ取り出す方法

Tags: bash

grepした結果のうち、特定の行のデータのみを取り出したいのですが
うまくいかないので、原因を知りたいです。

元ファイル

```
      Lost River=70  Delta TDR-98 TDS  
      Lost River=75  Delta TDR-10 TDS  
      AW F=75  Delta TDR-20 TDS  
      Lost River=30  Delta TDR-97 TDS
```

スクリプト

```
#!/bin/bash
cat $1 |grep Delta | head -n 1 | tail -n 1 | tail -c 10
cat $1 |grep Delta | head -n 2 | tail -n 1 | tail -c 10
cat $1 |grep Delta | head -n 4 | tail -n 1 | tail -c 10
```

出力したい値

```
-98
-10
-97
```

現在の出力

```
-98-10-97
```

Comment: 元ファイルの各行の先頭末尾にはスペース類が入っているのでしょうか？非表示文字が入っているならそれを明示してください。あと現在の文面では取り出す場所の規則がわかりません。どこを取り出したいのか、質問文を編集してくれると助かります。

Comment: もっと具体的に、入力の形式、得たい結果、書いたコードの根拠、何故うまくいかないかの考察、etc. を書きましょう。何もかも曖昧すぎます。表題が実際の要件と合ってないようですし。

Comment: 「特定の行のみ取り出す」ことはheadとtailで（目的によっては非効率かもしれませんが）実現できているように見えますがどうなのでしょうか。また、「現在の出力」として示されている物は貼り付けのミスなどではありませんか？ あのようには成らない気がします。

Comment: 編集後の「現在の出力」と「出力したい値」の違いは改行で区切られている事のみですので、echo で改行を入れればよさそうですね。しかし、やはり「現在の出力」が謎です。`tail -c 10` を3回行なえば30バイトの出力が期待出来ると思うのです。あと、もしかして縦の並びのことを「行」と表現されていますか？

Comment: 再現しませんね。スクリプトの内容に齟齬はないでしょうか。

Comment: 申し訳ございません
ご指摘の通り、不覚にもスペースが紛れておりました・・・。

Comment: 非効率な方法でしたので、質問自体は残します。どうもありがとうございます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

欲しいのは本当に行指定もしくは検出番号なのでしょうか？おそらく条件にマッチした行なのではないかと思います。間違ってたらすみません。ちなみにその場合、こういう処理は grep よりも sed が向いてると思います。

```
$ cat input | sed -n 's/^Lost\s\+River=[0-9]\+\s\+Delta\s\+TDR\(-[0-9]\+\).*/\1/p'
-98
-10
-97
```

Answer (score 1):

grep ではなく awk を使ってみます。3番目にマッチする行以外を処理します。

```
$ cat data.txt | awk -F '(TDR| TDS)' '/Delta/ && NR!=3{print $2}'
-98
-10
-97
```

**追記**

例えば、シェルスクリプトが以下の様になっていると、

```
#!/bin/bash

cat $1 |grep Delta | head -n 1 | tail -n 1 | tail -c 10 | head -c 3
cat $1 |grep Delta | head -n 2 | tail -n 1 | tail -c 10 | head -c 3
cat $1 |grep Delta | head -n 4 | tail -n 1 | tail -c 10 | head -c 3

$ ./hoge.sh data.txt
-98-10-97
```

となります。もしかして実際のスクリプトには `| head -c 3` が入っているのではないでしょうか？